# ERROR: more than one row returned by a subquery used as an expression SQL state: 21000

Tags: postgis

```
UPDATE trajectory_maritimes a SET id_traj_day= (SELECT CONCAT( imo_ship_no,
'-',EXTRACT(doy FROM arr_date_ts), '-', EXTRACT (year FROM arr_date_ts) )
FROM trajectory_maritimes b WHERE a.gid=b.gid);
```

I got this message:
ERROR:  more than one row returned by a subquery used as an expression
SQL state: 21000

What is wrong here?

Answer (score 2):

You probably have duplicate records in the `trajectory_maritimes` table

```
SELECT gid
FROM trajectory_maritimes 
GROUP gid
HAVING COUNT(*) >1;
```

The clean solution is to remove the duplicate, or to join on a truly unique field.

Alternatively, you can force the sub-query to return only one row per record. For a random one, you can add a `limit 1` clause

```
UPDATE trajectory_maritimes a 
SET id_traj_day= 
  (SELECT CONCAT( imo_ship_no,
    '-',EXTRACT(doy FROM arr_date_ts), '-', EXTRACT (year FROM arr_date_ts) )
  FROM trajectory_maritimes b 
  WHERE a.gid=b.gid
  LIMIT 1);
```